# php how to detect whole thousands

Tags: php, numbers

I am trying to detect if number in database is a whole thousands number.

i.e

```
25 = false
1000 = true
1578 = false
5000 = true
100000 = true
100005 = false
```

There ain't a way to tell if the number is a whole thousand, at least not with an PHP function that I know of.

I've tried creating an array with all thousands up to 1billion, but you can imagine how big that array is, then I would just do an **if (in_array())**.
When cleaning the code, the array is about 100k lines long, which ain't optimal if you ask me.

I've searched google for any way of doing this, but can't find any useful information.

Comment: Was not expecting anything, but you never know if there was somekind of work around with an PHP function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Modulo (%) operator is for this.

```
if ($num > 0 && $num % 1000 === 0) {
    echo "Divisible by 1000";
}
```

Note that you need to check if the $num is 0 because that will also test true because 0 % 1000 = 0

Comment: Worked out just as I needed it, thanks a lot! will mark this as the fully correct one

Answer (score 6):

Use the [modulo operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php): `%`

If `num % 1000 == 0`, `num` is divisible by 1000.

Comment: Will try it out, will get back to you in few mins

Answer (score 3):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Use the modulus operator.

```
if(x%1000==0) { //This tests to see if x/1000 has a remainder
    //This number is divisible by 1000
}
```